# Passing method parameters through template

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, simple-schema

I have the following method in meteor (I use schemas) which I call in order to insert an object in the database.

```
userAddOrder: function(newOrder, prize) {
        var currentPrize;
        if (prize == undefined) {
            currentPrize = undefined;
        }
        else{
            currentPrize = prize;
        }
        // Ininitalize the newOrder fields.
        // Check if someone is logged in
        if(this.userId) {
            newOrder.userId = this.userId;
            // Set the weight and price to be processed by the admin in the future
            newOrder.weight = undefined;
            newOrder.price = currentPrize;
            newOrder.status = false;
            newOrder.receiveDate = new Date();
            newOrder.deliveryDate = new Date();
            Orders.insert(newOrder);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    },
```

Broadly speaking, I have to pass it a "prize" parameter as a parameter. The problem is that despite the fact that I have the prize configured I could not find a way to pass it to the method through the template. One way I tried is to make a helper and try to pass it:

```
{{#autoForm schema="UserOrderSchema" id="userInsertOrderForm" type="method" meteormethod="userAddOrder,prizeRequest"}}
```

But it returns an error:

> "method not found"

Another way is to call the method in the js file by using a simple form(not the provided autoform). I think the second should work but I do not want to rewrite the whole Template. Is there a way to do it without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the auto form docs, the method has to take one parameter:

"Will call the server method with the name you specify in the meteormethod attribute. Passes a single argument, doc, which is the document resulting from the form submission."

So using a method based form isn't going to help you. Instead, use a 'normal' form:

```
{{#autoForm schema="UserOrderSchema" id="userInsertOrderForm" type="normal"}}
```

Then, add an auto form submit hook:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  userInsertOrderForm: {
    onSubmit: function (insertDoc, updateDoc, currentDoc) {
      var prize = ...;
      Meteor.call('userAddOrder', prize, function(err, result) {
         if (!err) {
            this.done();
         } else {
           this.done(new Error("Submission failed"));
         });
      });

      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I found another way. I just added a hidden field which value is the mentioned helper: {{> afQuickField name='price' value=prizeRequest type="hidden"}}

Comment: Indeed, that's simple :)